# Try to find folders with same naming file

Tags: powershell

I try to select Folders with a same naming file in the folder. All other Folders should be ignore.

Example:

Folder Structure

```
$RootPath
└───AD
    ├───ADGroup
    │       ADGroup.ps1
    │
    ├───ADUser
    │       ADUser.ps1
    │
    └───includes
```

The Command should only collect ADUser and ADGroup.

My Problem ist the Where-Object, precisely the Test-Path cmdlet

```bsh
$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $true -and (Test-Path -Path ''$_.FullName\$_.Name\.ps1'')}
```

Comment: you are using two single quotes around the path you want to test. those probably should be one _double_ quote, instead. this `''` should be replaced with this `"` ///// also, where are you testing to see if the path and the file have the same names/ ///// also also, the `.FullName` property of a file includes the FULL NAME - including the path AND the file name AND the extension. you likely should replace that with the property that holds the directory name.

Comment: Ok, but if i trie this, it doesnt work too. Then i become 0 Folders.
Test-Path -Path "'$_.FullName\$_.Name\.ps1'"

But i need the FullName Property, The FullName Property of an Folder get the absolute path to the folder, then i get the Folder name with $_.Name and add the Extension with .ps1, so i get the absolute Path to the file in de folder.

Comment: i think i understand what you are wanting. please take a look at my answer for some demo code.

Answer (score 0):

i think this does what you want. [*grin*] it gets the matching file types in the specified dir tree and then compares the parent dir of the file with the file base name.

```
$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = '*.ps1'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Filter $Filter -File -Recurse

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    if ($FL_Item.Directory.Name -eq $FL_Item.BaseName)
        {
        '{0} - parent dir & file base names are the same' -f $FL_Item.FullName
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning ('    {0} has different parent dir and file base names' -f $FL_Item.FullName)
        }
    }
```

output ...

```
C:\Temp\AlsoSameName\AlsoSameName.ps1 - parent dir & file base names are the same
WARNING:     C:\Temp\DiffName\Testing.ps1 has different parent dir and file base names
C:\Temp\SameName\SameName.ps1 - parent dir & file base names are the same
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in Lee_Dailey's comment

- to expand $variables inside strings you need double quotes
- 2nd problem is then to expand a compound variable like `$_.FullName` you need to enclose it also in `$()` => `"$($_.FullName)\$($_.Name).ps1"`

As Get-ChildItem supports the -Directory parameter and you better use `Join-Path` try this:

```
$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Recurse -Directory | 
    Where-Object {(Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName ($_.Name +'.ps1')))}
```

Comment: Hint for a new contributor: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (once you've got a [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) of 15 it will be seen)